# IF(ISSET($_FILES['imgfile'])) not checking if file is posting or not

Tags: php, file-upload

I have been trying to fix this from last 2 hours and no clue what is wrong here. i am checking the conditions if file is uploading or not, i mean, if there is no file selected from input, it will automatically select the file name already stored in database.
So here is my code, any help will be appreciated.
Here am checking if file is being uploaded or not.
when i do echo $imgFile; die();
it returns nothing. which means condition is applied here.

```
if(isset($_FILES['imgFile']['name'])){
$imgFile = $_FILES['imgFile']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['imgFile']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['imgFile']['size'];
}
```

and here is the code which are checking if file is uploading, if not then it will select from database.

```
if(isset($_FILES['imgFile']) && ($_FILES['imgFile'] != NULL)){
   $upload_dir = 'uploads/Cimages/'; // upload directory

   $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
   // valid image extensions
   $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

   $Cpic = sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)).".".$imgExt;

   if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){   
    // Check file size '10MB'
    if($imgSize > 10000 * 1024)    {
    $error[] = "Sorry, Image Size Should be Max 10 MB.";

    }
    else{
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$Cpic);
    }
   } // valid extensions
  else{
   $error[] = 'Only Jpg, Png and Gif images are Allowed.';
  }
  }

  else{
  $Cpic = $getCpic;
 }
```

**THE ERROR :** only jpg png are allowed. Even am not selecting anything. and when put echo $Cpic; die(); it shows a sha1 random number, which means that condition of checking file is posting or not, is not working. 
what i want is, make above code silent if file is not selected/uploading. and it choose the Cpic image from database. 
**PS**: $getCpic is already defined above in the codes. 
Thanks.!

Comment: Could you provide here html code form?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input class="form-control" type="file" name="imgFile"></form>

Comment: finally i solved it.! Thanks all for your help. what i did is if(empty($_FILES['imgFile']['name'])){
    $Cpic = $getCpic;
   } else { rest of the codes here }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that the default file is selected from the database `$getCpic` call that before processing the image upload - if the conditions within the image processing are OK then a new value will be assigned.

```
$var='imgFile';
$max=pow( 1024, 2 ) * 10;   // 10Mb
$Cpic = $getCpic;   // set the default

if( !empty( $_FILES[ $var ] ) ){

    $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $var ];
    $name=$obj->name;
    $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
    $size=$obj->size;
    $error=$obj->error;
    $upload_dir = __DIR__.'/uploads/Cimages/';

    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

        if( in_array( $ext, $valid_extensions ){
            if( $size < $max ){

                $Cpic = sha1( uniqid( rand(), true ) ) . "." . $ext;
                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $upload_dir.$Cpic );


            }else{
                $error[]='Sorry, that file is too large.';
            }
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Only Jpg, Png and Gif images are Allowed.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i am adding $CPIC = $getCpic without any condition, it will not work i guess. because am inserting that cpic in db, and if Cpic have already a value then second one will overwrite it? i dont get it.!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you dont use enctype="multipart/form-data"  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)?